# Chrome youtube videos logging me out

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

Pretty much a Ubuntu novice, currently running 64-bit AMD Ubuntu 12.04 with Cinnamon 2.0.14

Over the past couple months I've been getting logged out while viewing videos, typically youtube. Seems pretty random but repeatable within 2-3 minutes. All I have to do is change the volume, resize the window, or select different points for the video.

This seems to only happen in Chrome. I've not noticed this with Firefox or Konqueror, though I use them a lot less, so it might happen in those as well. I've removed/reinstalled Chrome, but same issue remains.

I looked in the following two files right after I got logged out/in - `/var/log/kern.log`  and  `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` and see something questionable to me:

**In /var/log/kern.log:**

```
Jul  8 21:44:34 steve-Ideapad-Z570 kernel: [ 1983.775557] Xorg[4188] general protection ip:7fda8d636420 sp:7fff2c5623d0 error:0 in Xorg[7fda8d5f0000+1f0000]
```

**In /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:**

```
[  1985.718] Segmentation fault at address (nil)
[  1985.718] 
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[  1985.718] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help. 
[  1985.718] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1985.718]
```

Not sure where or what else to look for.
Can anyone point me to the best way to troubleshoot this?

**Wondered if it might be memory related so I ran Memtest86+ but it didn't find anything failing. So, how is the best way to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you must have less RAM as far as I can say because chrome is very resource heavy. try checking system monitor for RAM usage. If the usage is more than 80% try getting a new RAM or adding a swap partition.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look over my issue and for suggesting a solution. However I actually have 8gb of RAM, and an 8GB swap space setup. This seems sufficient to me. Plus, this PC ran fine for 18 months. It's only recently that this condition surfaced.